# Python get type of a field of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Is there a way to get the field type of a class in Python, for use as a type annotation?

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
  field: str

def main() -> None:
  value: A.field = 123  # Want mypy to flag an error here
```

Where `A.field` is meant to refer to the type `str`, the type of `A.field`.

I'd like to do this to capture errors earlier for variables that may eventually be assigned to fields.

Comment: Nope. I don't think there is.

Comment: This is much too dynamic for a static type-checker to comprehend, I think.

Comment: @AlexWaygood I'm asking since I use a similar syntax from TypeScript, and was used to using it in C++. So in the general case it is something a static type checker could do.

Comment: Nonetheless, I don't think this is something that any of Python's static type-checkers are currently capable of. Happy to be proven wrong! :)

Comment: can you say more about why you need the errors to be caught earlier? Why not have them raised when you're making an `A`? I think the answer to this question may answer your question

Comment: @joel I want `value` to be the same type as `A.field` so that I can catch any potential type mismatches. I want the type dependent on the `field.A` type, in case it changes, or it's a complex type.

Comment: i mean specifically why catch them _early_. You'll get a mypy error when you try to create an `A` with the wrong argument type anyway. This will hold even if sth changes. What's your use case for getting the error message at a different point in the code?

Comment: @joel "later" might be in a different module or function, thus I won't know in my current function what is producing the wrong type.  Or it may be an argument to a function which needs a type. Or the variable may need to pass through some untyped code along the way (thus erasing the tracking).